# Table in crispy-forms (django) using FormHelper

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I want to show a table containing a set of model objects.

My model class:

```
from django.dbfrom django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class DamageKind(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_('damage kind'), max_length=64)
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('damage kind')
        verbose_name_plural = _('damage kinds')
```

my form class:

```
from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

from .models import DamageKind


class DamageKindList(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.damagekinds = kwargs.pop('damagekinds', [])
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My base template base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    {% block list %}

    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

my list_damagekinds.html:

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}                                                                   
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}                                                                  

{% block list %}                                                                              
     <form action="" method="post">                                                           
       {% csrf_token %}                                                                       
       {{ damagekind_form }}                                                                  
     </form>                                                                                  
{% endblock %}
```

and my views.py:

```
def list_damagekinds(request):
    damagekinds = DamageKind.objects.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'damage/list_damagekinds.html',
        {'damagekind_form': DamageKindList(damagekinds=damagekinds), }
    )
```

so my question is how I can make a table containing all the names of the damagekinds by not beeing editable, so just showing these. And **with** using the crispy_forms FormHelper and not code it into the template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my list_damagekinds.html

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}                                                                   
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}                                                                  

{% block list %}                                                                              
     <form action="" method="post">                                                           
       {% csrf_token %}               

       <table>                                                 
          {% for obj in damagekind_form %}        
             <tr> {{ obj.name }} </tr>
          {% endfor %}
       </table>      

     </form>                                                                                  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: but that looks not like the nicest way, shouldn't that be made by the FormHelper/DamageKindList-form?

Comment: As this values are not meant to be part of any http command (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) you may want to perform, where is the point in rendering it as a form? This is just a simple example - you can redesign it and add bootrap-classes or other css to it for a nicer look if it is that what concerns you.